# WPF - Prism eventAggregator doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, eventaggregator

I'm trying to learn how to build a WPF application but I'm encountering some problems when I use the EventAggregator class. 
Now I have the mainWindow.xaml that looks like:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:LoginViewModel}">
        <view:LoginView/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:HomeViewModel}">
        <view:HomeView/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:ReportViewModel}">
        <view:ReportView/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding BaseViewModel}"/>
</Grid>
```

So, my plan is switching views based on the value of the 'BaseViewModel' property.
When I need to change the view I publish an event like:

```
User user = session.login(Username, password);
if(user != null)
{
    //publishing the event
     _eventAggregator.GetEvent<OpenNewView().Publish((IBaseViewModel)container.Resolve<IHomeViewModel>());
}
```

And I pass to the event the class I should switch to. The example above works fine, but when I try to replicate this behavior on another view model there is something that doesn't trigger. This is when I public the event again:

```
_eventAggregator.GetEvent<OpenNewView>().Publish((IBaseViewModel)container.Resolve<IReportViewModel>());
```

But this isn't trigger on MainWindowModel (when the line above is executed correctly). Here when I subscribe the event:

```
    //ctor
    public MainViewModel(ILoginViewModel viewModel, IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        eventAggregator.GetEvent<OpenNewView>().Subscribe(OnOpenView);
        BaseViewModel = (LoginViewModel)viewModel;
    }
```

The method 'OnOpenView' is never executed.
Here my 'OpenNewView' class:

```
public class OpenNewView : PubSubEvent<IBaseViewModel>
{
}
```

Note: 
Here is how I declare the EventAggregator class (using Autofac):

```
builder.RegisterType<EventAggregator>().As<IEventAggregator>().SingleInstance();
```

So, I should have a single instance.

I'm new to the WPF world so I'm not sure I'm following the best practices.

Note 2: 
An important thing I forgot to mention:
if I replace the MainWindowViewModel constructor with:

```
    public MainViewModel(IHomeViewModel viewModel, IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        eventAggregator.GetEvent<OpenNewView>().Subscribe(OnOpenView);
        BaseViewModel = (HomeViewModel)viewModel;
    }
```

the pair publish-subscribe start working on my HomeViewModel. And that's a little weird...

Comment: Instead of sending the entire viewmodel, you can create a class of EventArgs and send only properties which are necessary. Also, please post your OpenNewView Event class.

Comment: Looks like you need to use an overload to the subscribe method, that take a bool as second parameter, and set that bool to true

Comment: @Skyuppercut edited my question with the the OpenNewView Event class. You are right, I should just pass the properties I need. Anyway that don't explain why the published event is not raised on the MainWindowViewModel class.

Comment: In Bootstrapper class (of Autofac), did you register the Viewmodels as IViewModels.? i.e., builder.RegisterType<LoginViewModel >().As<ILoginViewModel >() and such.? Did u check the inheritance of baseviewmodel and other vm's?

Comment: @Skyuppercut All should be correct. Anyway I updated my question again with an important thing: if I load the HomeViewModel at start, all works fine on this class and the event is subscribed correctly. It seems I can do it only the first time....